# how do i connect google app engine with mongolab

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, mlab

I want to use mongolab database in my website that i deploy on google app engine.

i go through many tutorials but i still not get it that how mlab uri which contains our username and password connect with google app engine?

in my node js file i use mongoose for connect to database but it gives me authentication failed error. do i need additional setup for connect mlab?

```
mongoose.connect(
    "mongodb://username:password@ds243212.mlab.com:43212/userinfo",
    {useNewUrlParser : true},
    {useMongoClient: true},
    function(err , db){
         if(err) console.log(err);
         console.log("connection success");
    }
```

this is simple way i tried.

Comment: Did you deploy or were you only trying locally?

Comment: @BrettJ i deploy it on google app engine and it works find except database connection.

Comment: Is this on the App Engine standard environment or flexible environment?

Comment: @BrettJ thanks for responding me , but i solved this problem i delete previous database and create newone and surprisingly it's works.